# How Ternary operator works in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i recently try out unity and saw in one of the youtube video clip they code like this:

```
    Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
```

i understand the Random.Range() but what does the the part after mean?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its the [Ternary Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4(v=vs.100).aspx) in C#.

Example:

```
condition ? expressionResultForTrue : expressionResultForFalse
```

If `Random.Range(0, 2) == 0` evaluates to `True` we get `-1` else `1`

Answer (score 1):

```
Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
```

This means, return `-1` if `Random.Range(0, 2) == 0`, else return `1`

Read on Ternary operator in c#

Answer (score 1):

Accordinaly to Unity documentation, Random.Range receives two parameters, minimum (inclusive) and maximum (exclusive). So it will return 0 or 1. If Random returns 0, this line will return -1, else 1.